# Do a histogram backwards projection in C#

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I have a float array, which serves as a histogram to an image. If i were to equalize that float array (histogram) how would i then apply it back to the image? (without using opencv/emgucv)

```
Mat image= CvInvoke.Imread(op.FileName, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ImreadModes.AnyColor);
Image<Gray, Byte> gray = image.ToImage<Gray, Byte>();
float[] hist = new float[256];
for(int i=0;i<gray.Rows;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<gray.Cols;j++)
    {
        hist[gray.Data[i, j, 0]] += 1;
    }
}
//doing something with the histogram, i've not implemented yet
//backwards projecting the hist back to the Image<Gray, Byte>, it doesnt matter if 've not done anything to the histogram yet
```

Comment: you use the float array as a lookup table for a backprojection of pixel values. what are you interested in? luminance, chrominance; grey-scale or color, ... and concerning the implementation, show the code you've got so far. from the c# tag and a list of excluded libraries alone it does not become clear, if you would like to work with an `IBitmap`, in GDI+, in DirectX or something else.

Comment: @CeeMcSharpface i have added the code